# How to count the number of courses offered by users in each city?

Tags: mysql

I need to count the number of courses offered by users in each city

I have the tables:

```
User: id, name, city_id

City: id, name

Course: id, name

Offer: id, user_id, course_id, vacancies
```

I need to print this report:

```
City  Course  Count
Milan English 67
Milan Spanish 12
Milan Italian 78
Roma  English 45
Roma  Spanish 32
```

MySQL code
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76c15e/1

Comment: please add a little more information about what exactly your report means?

Comment: MySQL can't easily format its results like that. Do it in an application programming language that processes the results of the query, and displays headers whenever the city changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call needed to generate the report.

```
SELECT 
 ci.name as 'city', 
 c.name as 'course', 
 count(o.id) as 'offers'  
FROM `user` u
 LEFT JOIN `offer` o on o.user_id = u.id
 LEFT JOIN `course` c on o.course_id = c.id
 LEFT JOIN `city` ci on u.city_id = ci.id
group by u.city_id, c.id
```

Comment: Please can you recheck? I edited the quesetion

Comment: @MariaBrands re-edited for you.